# Recommended approach in entity framework for one-to-one and one-to-many relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three entities `Customer`, `Product` and `Review`. A customer can have many products and many reviews. A product can have many reviews but only one owner. A review can have only one customer or one product. With this exercise I am trying to understand one-to-one and one-to-many (or vice versa) relationships using entity framework. From examples I have seen that for instance: Product entity is been written as:

```cs
public partial class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; } // with OwnerId 
    [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
    public Customer Owner { get; set; }
    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
// or
public partial class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OwnerId")] // in this case without public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Owner { get; set; }
    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

- Q: What is the best practice, and why would I need OwnerId property?
- Q: How are stored id of Owner so that I can query the Owners detail of a product?

**Based on the code below, how would be best written?**

```cs
namespace Domain.Entities
{
    public partial class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        // Navigation Properties
        public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Domain.Entities
{
    public partial class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
        public Customer Owner { get; set; }
        // Navigation Properties
        public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Domain.Entities
{
    public partial class Review
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Stars { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

model builder configurations

```cs
builder.ToTable("Customer")
    .HasMany(e => e.Reviews)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.Id);

builder.ToTable("Product")
    .HasKey(t => t.Id);

builder.ToTable("Review")
    .HasOne(d => d.Customer)
    .WithMany(p => p.Reviews)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

builder.ToTable("Review")
    .HasOne(d => d.Product)
    .WithMany(p => p.Reviews)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Ideally I would like to see a many-to-many relationship example in entity framework, and if you could modify the models so that relationship would be demonstrated would be perfect.

Thanks in advance and if you have any questions please let me know.

### Edit:

It seems like Product.id is foreign key to Customer.id which is weird, because I intended product id to be unique and not constrained to customer id
[image]

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: I think that `Customer` - `Product` should also be many-to-many. The same product can belong to multiple customers. I don't think the `Product` tables contains *instances* of products, in fact, the junctions `CustomerProduct` are the owned instances. If so, these junctions could also contain an optional review text. But that depends on business rules (only owners can write reviews).

Comment: @GertArnold Customer in my case is actually more like general user, but I could not use the word user because of the User from Identity package. Regarding product, I thought this more like eBay rather than like a shop that has many products, in that case would be needed a quantity value. But in this case a product is unique, that can be available, pending, sold or removed.

Comment: @Sachihiro what do you mean by " A review can have only one customer or one product"?

Comment: @Ghassen review can be made for customer or for users. Like "product with Id:1 is a good product", stars: 5. And for customers would be: "customer (user) with Id:1 did not deliver the product", stars: 1.

Comment: @Ghassen otherwise I would have had to use two tables, which perhaps is better anyway.

Comment: We don't have an entity called user, is it a mistake ?

Comment: @Ghassen As I commented to GertArnold above, Customer entity is more like the general user in my case, it's just the naming that it is a bit confusing and the reason why I am calling it customer and not user is that it mixes with the user from IdentityServer user entity.